# CentOS7 server VirtualBox guest on Ubuntu 15.10 screen issue

Tags: centos, virtualbox, resolution

I have created a virtual machine with a minimal CentOS 7 installation on my Ubuntu 15.10 guest system. I also installed the guest additions.
During the installation the installer issued a message, that the installation of the X11 components is skipped, as I have no desktop environment installed.

However, after installing the guest additions, resizing the screen does not work, and the settings for the virtual screen resolution of VirtualBox are greyed out.

What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: You won't get the resizing without x. For a more aesthetic minimal experience, I use ssh from the host and run the VM in headless mode.

Comment: I want to use the VM to play around with the machine before messing up our company server. This is the main reason why I did not install a desktop environment.

Comment: Is there a leightweight solution to my problem? I do not want to install full the gnome desktop for window resizing.

Comment: Using ssh without VBox open would be a lightweight solution. CentOS will have an openssh server although you may need to start it. Ubuntu has an ssh client. With VBox closed, open your Ubuntu terminal try something like VBoxHeadless --startvm "name_of_CentOS_VM". Then use ssh user@ip where user is your user on the CentOS VM and ip is its ip address.